# Getting null in subtraction of values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am getting null while trying to substracting two textbox and lablel fields using jquery. I want to display Balance amount on change of PaidAmount and Discount textbox change of value. I tried a lot but didn't find any loops on my own. If anyone can help me i would appreciate for the same.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="Total Charges :"></asp:Label>    
<asp:Label ID="lblGrandTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="0"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="Discount"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDiscount" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Paid Amount"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPaid" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text="Balance"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="lblBalance" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Text="0"></asp:Label>
```

//scripts

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtPaid").keypress(function () {
            var val1 = parseInt($("#lblGrandTotal").val());
            var val2 = parseInt($("#txtPaid").val());
            $("#lblBalance").val(val1 - val2);
        });
    });
```

Comment: are you sure `lblGrandTotal` is the client id, check the generated html to see what is the id of the generated label... also `lblGrandTotal` is a label element not a input element so `.val()` won't work... use `.text()` instead...

Comment: When you type from console `$("#txtPaid")` does you get some results? Maybe old webforms generate such a html code that ID does not match id in DOM.

Comment: In addition to the above comments, it may be worthwhile just adding the actual, generated HTML to your question to help us debug a bit better.

Comment: Thanks to all.... I replaced .val() with .text() now i am getting an error value "NaN" on lblBalance.

Comment: There's no TextBox associated with `lblGrandTotal`, and you can't grab a val from label can you? Fix the ASP/HTML and the javascript/jQuery should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. it works for me.

```
 $("#txtPaid").keyup(function () {
        var val1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=lblGrandTotal.ClientID %>').innerHTML);
        var val2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%=txtPaid.ClientID %>').value);
        if (val1 != null && val1.toString() != "NaN" && val2 != null && val2.toString() != "NaN") {
            $("#<%=lblBalance.ClientID %>").html(val1 - val2);
        }
        else {
            $("#<%=lblBalance.ClientID %>").html("0");
        }
    });
```